# Can more then one Hamilton circuit in a graph exist?

Tags: graph-theory

Are Hamilton circuits similar to isomorphic graphs where there isn't one definitive correct answer, but rather multiple answers of different forms that are correct?

Answer (score 3):

Consider a complete graph $K_n$: **every** sequence of the $n$ vertices is a Hamilton path, and since every vertex is adjacent to every other vertex, there is an edge from its last vertex to its first to make it a Hamilton circuit.

There are $n!$ permutations of the vertices, and each permutation has $n$ possible starting points for the circuit and can be traversed in two directions, so $K_n$ has $\frac{n!}{2n}=\frac12(n-1)!$ different undirected Hamilton circuits.